# Can you remove a spell counter to activate an ability during battle?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Breaker the Magical Warrior](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Breaker_the_Magical_Warrior) reads:

> If this card is Normal Summoned: Place 1 Spell Counter on it (max. 1). [...] You can remove 1 Spell Counter from this card, then target 1 Spell/Trap on the field; destroy that target.

I attacked my friend's Breaker with my [Blue-Eyes White Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_White_Dragon), destroying it. My friend said: "Well, before it dies, I remove the spell counter to destroy your trap."

Can she do that?

Comment: Good question. (I'm starting to worry about this friend of yours...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can she do that?

**No. As Breaker's effect is not quick-play.**

His effect is Speed 1, which means it can only be activated during the owner's Main Phases.

In Yugioh there are 3 speeds of effects:

- Speed 1: As indicated before, can be activated during the owner's Main Phases. You can't activate a Speed 1 effect in response to any activation or condition.
- Speed 2: These can be activated technically anytime, and can be chained in response to Speed 1 or Speed 2 effects (unless otherwise restricted). In spell cards these are the ones with the lightning symbol, or trap cards without any symbol for example (there are others, of course).
- Speed 3: These are exclusive for Counter Trap Cards (the ones with the arrow symbol). These can be activated in response to *any* spell speed, and only a Counter can be activated in response to another.

So, no. Breaker can't do that as it is Speed 1 effect.

Comment: Okay, related question: I polymerized a Blue Eyes Twin Burst Dragon into play, then tried to play a Lord of D., but before I could she A. activated Call of the Haunted to Special Summon her Dark Magician Girl, then used Magical Dimension to destroy my Blue Eyes Twin Burst Dragon. I read the Spell Speed explanations but I still can't tell if that was legal. Both the quick-spell Magical Dimension and the trap activation are Spell Speed 2, but can she just interject them into my main phase after I resolved Polymerization?

Comment: @Aerovistae This could be legal in this scenario: In response to normal summon Lord of D, both you and opp take turn on possible chain start (trigger being being normal summoned), opp can then do call of the haunted, and in response to *that* other summon can activate Magical Dimension. Note that if Magical D is not activated on response of that other summon, then you would then have turn of action (after both of you passing chance to chain) in which case opp cannot just say "oh, I forgot to activate this..."